# Can't connect to WSL2 from Visual Studio

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio, wsl2

I've got a Windows 11 computer with Visual Studio 2022. I can connect to the ssh server inside WSL2 through localhost with putty. But when I try to add a connection for WSL2 inside Visual Studio connection manager with localhost, port 22, username, password I get an error inside the log

```
C:\Users\***\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\RemoteConnectionsLogging
```

... saying ...

```
10:03:13.5244226 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.RemoteSystemBase: Connecting over SSH to localhost:22
10:03:15.5765128 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.HostKeyVerifier: Connection failed.
10:03:15.5825127 [Info, Thread 1]   liblinux.HostKeyVerifier: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte
```

The error is in German, but it says that a TCP-connection couldn't be established to localhost. When I try to connect to localhost:22 with ncat from the Win32 nmap-package, I can see the first step of the SSH-handshake from the ssh-server inside WSL2:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
```

Comment: Perhaps this is about IPv6 vs IPv4. Try connecting to `127.0.0.1` explicitly, instead of `localhost`.

Comment: @DanielB: Yes, although MS says that you've to use localhost 127.0.0.1 works. It looks for me that localhost is preferedly resolved via IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to SSH into a WSL2 distro:

- Install `openssh-server` in WSL:

  ```
  sudo apt install openssh-server
  ```
- As Windows already uses the default port for our SSH, usually 22,
  replace (for example) by 2222:
  edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the following three changes:

  ```
  Port 2222
  ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
  PasswordAuthentication yes
  ```
- To remove the requirement of a password for starting the ssh service,
  edit `/etc/sudoers.d/` by adding the following line:

  ```
  %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh *
  ```
- Finally start the service:

  ```
  service ssh start
  ```

More information in
[SSH into a WSL2 host remotely and reliably](https://medium.com/@gilad215/ssh-into-a-wsl2-host-remotely-and-reliabley-578a12c91a2).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using *127.0.0.1* instead of *localhost*.

On modern systems, *localhost* resolves to both IPv4 (*127.0.0.1*) and IPv6 (*::1*), with IPv6 coming first. Normally, this isn’t a problem, because software will very quickly fall back to IPv4 if IPv6 doesn’t work.

The fallback does not work here because it is simply not implemented in *SSH.NET*, the underlying library used by Visual Studio. It simply takes the first address (so *::1*) and goes with that.

Supposedly, localhost forwarding in WSL also works for IPv6 and *sshd* would usually also listen on IPv6, who knows.